# Warning: include(../includes/db.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: php

This is the problem I am facing now Can you please suggest me to get rid of this problem. Before I have not get this problem It was working nicely now I don't know what happened the path is correct only. Anyone please solve it...

> Warning: include(../includes/db.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php on line 3 
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening '../includes/db.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php on line 3 
>   Warning: include(functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php on line 4 
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening 'functions.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php on line 4

Comment: path might have changed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: where you db file put in include folder or in portfolio folder

Comment: db file is in portfolio include folder

Comment: Aslam Patel C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error posted, it seems to be that the include_path is referring to the path (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') while the PHP files are included in some other folder.

You need to update the include_path variable to point to the correct location. You can find this in the php.ini file.

Comment: Actually the path is correct only before it was working now only I am facing this problem see the path C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes

Comment: What is the value of include_path in php.ini?

Comment: it is showing in the php.ini file is:  UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path=C:\xampp\php\PEAR
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path @kalyan Srinivas Limkar

Comment: You can set the include_path value in your PHP code. Try this:

Comment: You can set the include_path value in your PHP code. Try this:
<?php
set_include_path('/usr/lib/pear');
?>

Comment: I have add this <?php set_include_path('/usr/lib/pear'); ?> in same file i.e., php.ini file??? Or where I have to add this

Comment: This has to be added to the PHP file which is giving you the error. The set_include_path value should be set at the top of the PHP file.

For example, 
<?php
            set_include_path('<filepath>');
.....
?>

Comment: I got solution for this actually I have added functions.php file path to the db.php file I removed that then its working properly right now!!! will if I got any other probs I wil ask here

Comment: Thank you very much :)... @Kalyan Srinivas Limkar

Answer (score 1):

Computers don't lie, if it says it doesn't see it, then it is not there

Make sure you are making it look at the right place, and if I will advise you do it manually also to confirm

I also suspect it is an issue arising from using relative paths. Please make sure the path is right considering where you are currently calling the file from

e.g calling include(../includes/db.php) from index.php is different from calling it from admin/index.php

EDIT

If your are calling from C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php to C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes

then

```
include(../../includes/db.php);
```

is the right syntax to use

Hope this Helps

Comment: Actually the path is correct only before it was working now only I am facing this problem see the path C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes

Comment: this prob arised.. Warning: include(./admin/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes\db.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening './admin/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes\db.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\includes\admin_header.php on line 3 @funsho olaniyi

Comment: that is progress, change  include(./admin/functions.php): to  include(admin/functions.php): and make sure there is C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\admin\function.php file

Comment: I got solution for this actually I have added functions.php file path to the db.php file I removed that then its working properly right now!!! will if I got any other probs I wil ask here. Thank you @Funsho Olaniyi

Answer (score 1):

I have had this the same issue before and it ended up being something dumb on my part i forgot to start the MySQL on the XAMPP control panel. I'm sure i'm late the the party on the answer but hope it can help someone later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but i just reply for those who might get the same error .

assuming you are storing header.php in your includes directory and its not beside your index.php,so when you include bd.php into your header.php and then including your header.php into your index.php pay attention that apache knows index.php direcotroy as your pwd so if you have set that relative path for db.php based on header.php directory its not gonna work.you can use absolute path to avoid this or just set you relative path based on relative location of db.php from index.php

Answer (score 0):

It look likes, the files you are trying to include in your php codes, are not on that place. Try to save all your include files in a particular folder and then call it wherever you want to call it.
suppose your index.php file is in xampp/htdocs/your_folder_name/index.php , then simply create a folder name whatever you want to name it inside your folder name your_folder_name/your_new_folder and save all your files which you want to include, as if you are saving db.php then call it on the top of your page as:

```
<?php include("your_new_folder/db.php");?>
```

Comment: Actually the path is correct only before it was working now only I am facing this problem see the path C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\includes

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you are coding your relative path. 
I am assuming you got this error when your app made reference to `admin_header.php`, which has an `include()` to try and call  `{document_root}/porfolio/admin/includes/db.php`. My educated guess is it contains your implementation of the connection string to the database.

The correct relative path should be:  `include('../../includes/db.php');`

This link should give you a better understanding of relative paths (and paths in general).
https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I had this problem and then realised WAMP had crashed (or maybe I didn't start it). Either way, WAMP wasn't running on my local machine, so... doh.

This should be the very first thing you check (in line with, "is it plugged in?").

Answer (score -1):

Try removing relative paths (`"../"`)
e.g. change `include(../includes/db.php)` to `include(includes/db.php)`